# Agrupar registros por producto_id - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy intentando agrupar unos registros pero no lo consigo.

**Tabla Orders**

| id | user_id | ticket |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 202310025 |
| 2 | 3 | 202310025 |

**Tabla Orders products**

| id | ticket | product_id | talla |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202310025 | 3 | XL |
| 2 | 202310025 | 3 | L |
| 3 | 202310025 | 55 | S |

**Cuando quiero ver un pedido en una vista:**

Controlador:

```
$pedido = Orders::with('productos', 'cliente')->where('ticket', $slug)->first();
```

Relación tabla Orders:

```
public function productos()
{
    //De este modo traigo los productos
    return $this->hasMany(OrdersProducts::class, 'ticket', 'ticket'); 
}
```

Mi impresión en la vista:

```
//De esta forma itero todos los productos que hay en el pedido.
@foreach ($pedido->productos as $item)
   {{ $item->producto->nombre }}
   {{ $item->producto->talla }}
   {{ $item->producto->cantidad }}
   ......
@endforeach
```

Entonces hay pedidos que pueden llevar un mismo producto pero en distinta talla, hay posibilidad de agruparlos y mostrar en tallas, todas las tallas y cantidad todas las cantidades?? También decir que hay pedidos que pueden ser productos distintos y a la vez en el mismo pedido uno con las misa id de producto.

Me pueden guiar por favor??

Comment: Si el ticket no es una llave única dentro de Orders, entonces no debiera usarse en la relación con el pivote. De otra manera se te cruzarán datos de distintos pedidos.

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes que agregarle un groupBy a la consulta

```
$pedido = Orders::with('productos', 'cliente')
          ->where('ticket', $slug)
          ->groupBy('product_id')
          ->get();
```

esto de devolvera una coleccion de objectos cuyo indice va a ser el product_id.

recuerda recorrer esta coleccion con:

```
foreach($pedido as $key => $value) {
  //code here
}
```

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, pero el problema es que es un `->first()` he itero los productos a través de una relación, por lo que si pongo lo que me dices me devuelve que no existe  `product_id` ya que los busca en la tabla `Orders` @Daniel Correa Hincapie